# WPF Unit testing framework

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, frameworks

Is there a framework that supports UnitTesting of WPF applications. It should not be to difficult to establishe, because I don't want that writing the tests takes ten times longer than implementing a small feature.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a WPF specific unit test framework. Is it the XAML code you want to unit test? Your UI layer should be as thin as possible - then you can unit test the rest of the code with regular unit test framework like NUnit, Xunit, MbUnit etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with NUnit, just like you'll do with any other component.

Optionally you can try MVC.

See CodeProject for [MVCtoUnitTestinWPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVCtoUnitTestinWPF.aspx)

Hope it serves.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [IcuTest](http://www.nxs-7.com/icu/). It simplifies WPF unit testing a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) test projects within visual studio can be used to unit test WPF applications, just like they can be used to test windows forms, asp.net and asp.net mvc applications, services, etc etc.
2) Testing takes time.  Sometimes it takes ten times longer to test a piece of code than it did to write it.  There's no TDD fairy.

Answer (score 0):

The open source verification utility ApprovalTests (www.approvaltests.com or nuget ) will easily test Wpf views.

You can see it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc_ty03lZ9U

I'd recommend watching the winforms video 1st though, as it goes into more of the theory of how to test views in general: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKeKBjoSfJ8

The code itself will look like

```
WpfApprovals.Verify(yourWpfView);
```

and it will take a screenshot and compare it agains a golden master.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure about WPF unit testing, but for Silverlight there is you have [SilverUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/CThru/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SilverUnit%20examples&referringTitle=Home) and [Microsoft Silverlight Unit Test](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut).

Comment: -1: WPF is .net (Silverlight is an entirely different entitty) - see http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/userblogs/runarj/blogView?entry=3366522423

Answer (score -1):

I heard that [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) is good - though I haven't tested it myself yet..