# Good resources for Unit Testing with MVVM

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I am reasonably new to WPF and MVVM but I understand the basics. The problem I am having is trying to find some good resources to learn unit testing with MVVM. I am new to unit testing.

Can anyone recommend some good resources whether it's blogs, videos, or even books.

Comment: Unit testing MVVM should be no different than unit testing in general. You just have to remember to structure your code in such a way that makes it easy to unit test - avoid creating hard dependencies between modules, avoid puting code in the code behind, but prefer ViewModel classes etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic has been widely discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use

[WPF Unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915578/wpf-unit-testing-framework)

You can find plenty of similar questions in the Related questions list.

Arrange, Act Assert is helpful for structuring your unit tests for better readability. 
http://www.arrangeactassert.com/why-and-what-is-arrange-act-assert/

You mentioned you are new to unit testing. I would suggest reading a few free ebooks discussing the topic in general, to get a good feel of unit testing. After all, unit tests are independent of the framework used in the project, because you should be testing individual classes, methods and not entire components.

Of course reading a good book is always worth it:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_kk_1?rh=i%3Astripbooks%2Ck%3Atest+driven+development&keywords=test+driven+development&ie=UTF8&qid=1344460674

MSDN Magazine has great articles about unit testing:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=unit%20testing&Refinement=118&ac=8

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx for an example MVVM application with unit tests.

That should be enough to start.

Answer (score 2):

[The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) is good book for you. And [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for mocking framework